# AIX lquerypv equivalent in Linux (RHEL/Cent OS)

Tags: linux, centos, rhel

In AIX we can view raw data of hdisk by issuing following comamand

```
lquerypv -h /dev/hdisk0
```

This displays data in hexa decimal format. More of like hex editor.

What is the equivalent command in Linux based system

Comment: `hexdump`? What info are you after?

Comment: for asm database luns should be formatted. so before executing dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/hdiskX we usually do lquerypv. I was wondering if the equivalent command is available in linux

Comment: Can you provide expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i was looking for. Finally i got it with the help of cfdisk command.

```
cfdisk -P r /dev/sda
```

Where sda is your disk, P is for printing partition table to screen and r is for print raw output.
Here is the sample output.

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Look I think that you can replace the command you need with the following

```
sudo cat /dev/sda2|head -n 5|strings
```

You can change the number of head lines as you want and you can also remove the head part and append a "less" to go through all the required disk or whatever

```
sudo cat /dev/sda2|strings|less
```